# Ajax call is not invoking server side method

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '#year', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var startDate = new Date();
     alert(startDate);
     plotGraph('year',startDate);
});    
function plotGraph(detail,dt) {
     alert(detail+" "+dt);
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "BillnAmount",
          data: {detail: detail,dt:dt},
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              alert('succe');
          }
          error: function(data) {
              alert("not able to fetch data");
          }
    });
}
```

I am using above program to call below server side language Above code is executing properly and success alert message is showing but it is not executing the server method `plotBillnAmount()`

```
public String plotBillnAmount() {
     System.out.println("plotBillnAmount() ");
     System.out.println("detail " + getDetail() + " dt " + getDt());
}
```

What may be the problem??

Comment: replace `url: "BillnAmount"` by the absolute url ( `url: "http://yoursite.com/BillAmount"` for example ). It could solve the pb.

Comment: You're missing a `,` between your `success` and `error` handlers.

Comment: ok    `,`     added      . between success and error

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant  I am testing on local host should i use local host complete path

Comment: @xrcwrn if your page is 'http://localhostXXXXXXX/mypage' then use 'http://localhostXXXXXXX/BillnAmount'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I am removing dt parameter it is calling the url.  I conclude that the date I am sending in not in proper way/format could you please tell me what changes should I do to send date.

Answer (score 0):

you need to mark your method as static with [webmethod] tag
and your url page.aspx/methodname

jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/showMsg",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("not able to fetch data");
                } 
            });
```

C#

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string showMsg()
 {
    return "Hello world";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**hello try this one.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $.getJSON("http://", function(data) {
        $.each(data.categories, function(index, item) {

          categoriesId.push(item.productName);


        }
              );
        for (i = 0; i < categoriesId.length; i++) {

            alert(categoriesId[i]);
        }
      }
               );

    }
                     );
  </script>
```

***if you are get alert from your webservice then tell me and you you get some problem then send me your webservices i will display data your convenient format.***

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your data field like this :

```
data: '{"detail":"' + detail + '", dt":"' +dt'"}',
```

Also, your url field should say which file contains your method:

```
url: "file.aspx/BillnAmount",
```

Comment: I think it's wrong, you can pass objects. It is supposed to be stringified in json, or urlencoded, by this call.

Comment: Well, he could, but he needs to use the json "stringify" method which is not shown explicitly in here.